# How to use URLSession delegates with scheduled BackgroundTasks framework

Tags: ios, background-task, urlsession

I am trying out my first code with Apple's BackgroundTasks framework to schedule the downloading of files from a remote website on a periodic basis.  These files contain updated data that my app needs to perform its operations.  I have an existing class called PopularDataDownloader that downloads the file in the background utilizing URLSession as shown below:

```
class PopularDataDownloader: NSObject{
    var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

    lazy var downloadsSession: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MY-UNIQUE-IDENTIFIER")


        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    func startDownload(url: URL){
        let downloadTask = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTask.resume()
        self.downloadTask = downloadTask
    }
}


extension PopularDataDownloader: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard let sourceURL = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else {
            return
        }
        print("Finished downloading...")
        print(location)
        // process file...
    }
}
```

This logic described so far works as designed when initiated via user interaction (button press for example) within the app.  My problem is I'm not sure how to wire this so that it can be scheduled via the BackgroundTasks framework.  Within my AppDelegate I have the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.test.data.refresh", using: nil) { (task) in
        self.handleDataRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
    }
    return true
}
func handleDataRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    task.expirationHandler = {
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
    }

    let downloader = PopularDataDownloader()
    downloader.startDownload(url: URL(string: "URL_FOR_DATA")!)    
    task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)

    scheduleBackgroundDataRefresh()
}


func scheduleBackgroundDataRefresh() {
    let task = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.test.data.refresh")
    task.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
    do {
      try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(task)
    } catch {
      print("Unable to submit task: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I can see the scheduled tasks firing off, but my issue is the call to startDownload returns immediately and before the file finishes downloading and is processed since the URLSessionDownloadDelegate is where that logic occurs.  My question is how should I implement a scheduled background task that relies on URLSession's delegate capabilities?  Is it possible to implement a closure (completion handler) for the startDownload function that then is stored and then utilized in the delegate?  Is there some other design I should be utilizing?

Comment: Without trying anything, `task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)` is called BEFORE the download has actually completed. Remember, the actual request is been executed in a different thread/context so it will return immediately.  You need to monitor the state of the download and only when it's completed (or failed) call `setTaskCompleted` with the appropriate state

Comment: Right, I get that I don’t want to call the task complete until after the file is downloaded and processed, I’m just not sure how to monitor it like you say.

Comment: Maybe look at using [`URLSession#downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411511-downloadtask)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to work if you use it in the background via URLSessionConfiguration.background, it throws this error: "Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead."

Comment: If you are using a background url session then the background task and the download tasks are separate. You initiate the background download from your background task and your background task is then complete. The download will then complete out of process and you will get a callback via `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in your app delegate

Comment: Thanks for the response Paulw11, I'm not sure I fully understand.  Are you saying that for my use case I should only call setTaskCompleted(success: true) for the initiation of the background download but not worry about its outcome when making that call?  Also within my URLSessionDownloadDelegate I have logic that is fired off when the download completes, are you suggesting that I move that logic to handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession in app delegate?  If that is what you are proposing, can you explain why that location is preferable to the URLSessionDownloadDelegate?